# How to check or compare if an object is in an array list?

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I have created a pojo class like this:-

```
public class User{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // Setter and getter methods
}
```

Now I have created array and added some users in array:

```
 List<User> users=new Arraylist<>();

 User user1=new User();
 user1.setId(1);
 user1.setName("ABC");
 users.add(user1);

 User user2=new User();
 user2.setId(2);
 user2.setName("MNO");
 users.add(user2);

 //...
```

Now I want to find user 1 is in users list. If the size of users is large, then how can I perform quick search?

Comment: Do you want to search user by his ID ?

Comment: Override `equals` and use method `contains` of `List` interface,

Comment: @hsz yes i want to search user by ID

Comment: Then your Question title is quite misleading. You should consider changing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[List#contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method do what you want. And that method uses the `equals()` method to find out if two objects are the same. So, just override `equals()`  and also override the `hashCode()`.

If you want to search them really quick by Id, I would prefer to take a `HashMap<Integer,User>` rather than `List`.

Comment: ` If the size of users is large then how can i perform quick search?`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform quick search you can either use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (or [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) if you want to keep track of number of duplicates) to store the data, you will also need to implement [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) and [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) - and use a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) or alternatively use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and provide a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Another solution would be to maintain the list sorted (with regards to some `Comparator`) and use [`Collections.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T))

Answer (score 0):

```
users.indexOf(user1);
```

If this returns -1 then the `user1` doesn't exists in the ArrayList. I believe this would be the simplest way to know if a user object exists on your List.

you can have a condition like:

```
boolean userExists = (users.indexOf(aUserObject) >= 0) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement `equals()` and `hascode()` as follows:

```
class User{
private int id;
private String name;

// Setter and getter methods
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (object == null || object.getClass() != getClass()) {
        result = false;
    } else {
        User user = (User) object;
        if (this.id==user.id) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public int hashCode(Object o){
    return id;
  }
}
```

Now you can simply check for object equality as follows:

```
List<User> users=new Arraylist<>();

User user1=new User();
user1.setId(1);
user1.setName("ABC");
users.add(user1);

User user2=new User();
user2.setId(2);
user2.setName("MNO");
users.add(user2);

if(users.contains(user2)) // this would check for a presence of user2 in the list

//...
```

Note: equality is got through class `User` `id` field. You can choose any field or implement any other logic to it.

Comment: Your code is wrong. If a.equals(b) then a.hashCode() == b.hashCode(). As you hashCode use the field name wich is not tested in the equals method the contract is not fulfilled.